# What is the Swift way of copying a range of values from a Collection to a MutableCollection?

Tags: swift, generics, memcpy

It is easy to copy values from a `Collection` to a [`RangeReplaceableCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection), I even managed to write a little generic function to summarize how to do it (assuming destination is large enough):

```
func copy<Destination: RangeReplaceableCollection, Source: Collection>(
    dest: inout Destination,
    source: Source)
where Source.Element == Destination.Element
{
    let startIndex = dest.startIndex
    let endIndex = dest.index(startIndex, offsetBy: source.count)
    dest.replaceSubrange(startIndex..<endIndex, with: source)
}
```

This is possible because of [`replaceSubrange(_:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection/3128731-replacesubrange) (which can even handle source and destination of different lengths, but I don't need that here).

However it does not seem to be possible to write an equally terse version if my destination is a [`MutableCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mutablecollection/). The only way seems to be a handwritten loop:

```
func copy<Destination: MutableCollection, Source: Collection>(
    dest: inout Destination,
    source: Source)
where Source.Element == Destination.Element
{
    var index = dest.startIndex
    for element in source {
        dest[index] = element
        index = dest.index(after: index)
    }
}
```

This seems too cumbersome to be right... Did I miss something and there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Not clear what's the goal here. You code replaces the original rangereplacecollection with elements from another collection. It will always replace the prefix elements of the original. If the other collection is bigger than the destination it totally replaces the original one.

Comment: Note that if the other collection is bigger than the original it would crash your app. Btw from the `MutableCollection` docs **The MutableCollection protocol allows changing the values of a collection’s elements but not the length of the collection itself. For operations that require adding or removing elements, see the RangeReplaceableCollection protocol instead.**

Comment: I am still trying to figure out what's the purpose of your method if you are only working with collections of the same size. Why not simply `oldCollection = newCollection`?